# Como utilizar session em php android

Tags: php, session

Estou criando um app android, onde quando executado pede login e ao usuario

O android verifica login e senha em um web service feito em `php` ate ai tudo bem esta tudo correndo certo .. porem quando peço informações ao banco de dados realizando um select em php em web service novamente ele me retorna todos os dados do bando de dados e não apenas a do usuario logado.

Acredito que quando eu faço a verificação do login eu tenha que armazenar o codigo da empresa via (session) e utilizar o mesmo na outra pagina de php para quando usar o select com a session ele me retorne apenas os dados do usuario

#### Código PHP

```
<php
SESSION_START();
mysql_connect('localhost','','');
mysql_select_db('bd') or die (mysql_error());

$username = $_GET['a'];
$password = $_GET['d'];


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tab_Config where Login='$username' and Senha='$password'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        echo $row['Cod_Empresa'];
        $_SESSION['Cod_Empresa'] =  $row['Cod_Empresa'];

    }

else{
echo "";
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: já tentou utilizar SharedPreferences no android? Depois que você fizer a consulta, pode gravar lá, nas outras requisições, você verifica se tem algo salvo e manda como parâmetro. aqui tem um exemplo de como utilizar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: Creio que você deva guardar no app o SESSION_ID, pois para utilizar a mesma sessão, será necessário enviar essa ID via GET nas suas requisições. Veja este link: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php